# How do I differentiate: $y=x-A+\arcsin(B(\sin(A-\arcsin(\frac{\sin x}{B}))))$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do you differentiate: $y=x-A+\arcsin(B(\sin(A-\arcsin(\frac{\sin x}{B}))))$

$A$ and $B$ are just constants.

I know that if: $$y=\arcsin(x)$$ then: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

But how would you deal with the situation above where you have so many sines and arcsines within each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the whole solution at [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate%20x-a%2Barcsin(b*sin(a-arcsin(sin(x)%2Fb)))), it doesnt look a big deal. The chain's rule is just applied succesively.

$$
\frac{df}{dx}=1-\frac{\cos(x)\cos(a-\arcsin(\frac{\sin(x)}{b}))}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{b^2}}\sqrt{1-b^2\sin^2(a-\arcsin(\frac{sin(x)}{b}))}}
$$

In the general case with a series of function compositions:
$$
f(x)=\{\circ_{i=1}^n f_i\}(x)= \{f_1  \circ \cdots \circ f_n \} (x)
$$

The derivative of the function composition series would be:
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=f_1'(\{\circ_{i=2}^n f_i\}(x)) f_2'(\{\circ_{i=3}^n f_i\}(x)) \cdots f_n'(x)
$$

in which you again evaluate each component derivative at the remaining composition series.